# C++ How to save file stream in memory to another location

Tags: c++, logging

I have regular text log file in memory,

```
ofstream logfile;
```

It is encapsulated in a Logger class, with a destructor closing that file,

```
class Logger {
    ofstream logfile;
    ~Logger() {
        logfile.close();
    }
    ...
}
```

What I want to do is, at the `Logger` destructor, save another copy of log file to another directory.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to copy a *file* ? Or are you asking how to use your exiting stream to perform that operation?

Comment: @WhozCraig I want to save the same stream to another file

Comment: `iostreams` are merely buffered filters, data is just passing through.  What goes out of an output stream can't be retrieved back later from the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Logger
{
    private:
        std::fstream logfile; //fstream allows both read and write open-mode.
        std::fstream secondfile;
        const char* second;

    public:
        Logger(const char* file, const char* second)
        : logfile(), secondfile(), second(second)
        {
            //open for both read and write, the original logfile.
            logfile.open(file, std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
        }

        void Write(const char* str, size_t size)
        {
            logfile.write(str, size); //write to the current logfile.
        }

        ~Logger()
        {
            logfile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
            secondfile.open(second, std::ios::out); //open the second file for write only.
            secondfile<<logfile.rdbuf(); //copy the original to the second directly..

            //close both.
            logfile.close();
            secondfile.close();
        }
};

int main()
{
    Logger l("C:/Users/Tea/Desktop/Foo.txt", "C:/Users/Tea/Desktop/Bar.txt");
    l.Write("HELLO", 5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the best approach, but it's a working one.
You can create a new instance of `std::ofstream` and copy all of your data into it.

Comment: yep that would be the easiest approach but I want to know an alternative, if there is one